# Initialization of get-only property in owner-object initializer

Tags: c#, object-initializers

last time I came across a construct in C# Object Initializer:

having:

```
public class Class1
{
    public Class2 GetterOnlyProperty { get; private set; }

    public Class1()
    {
        this.GetterOnlyProperty = new Class2();
    }
}
```

the initialization may be as follow:

```
var class1 = new Class1()
{
    GetterOnlyProperty =
    {
        Prop1 = Value1,
        Prop2 = Value2,
        …
    }
};
```

Please note that there is no `new` keyword after GetterOnlyProperty, the Instance for GetterOnlyProperty must be created in constructor of Class1, otherwise `NullReferenceException` will be thrown. This instance is taken and properties are initialized.

It works like a charm, but I haven't found documentation of this feature in MSDN. Is this feature documented? Could you provide me with a link to the documentation?

Thanks in advance!
Wojtek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in section §7.6.10.2 Object initializers of the C# Spec.

> A member initializer that specifies an object initializer after the equals sign is a nested object initializer, i.e. an 
>   initialization of an embedded object. Instead of assigning a new value to the field or property, the assignments in 
>   the nested object initializer are treated as assignments to members of the field or property. Nested object 
>   initializers cannot be applied to properties with a value type, or to read-only fields with a value type.

As for nested collection initializers:

> A member initializer that specifies a collection initializer after the equals sign is an initialization of an embedded 
>   collection. Instead of assigning a new collection to the field or property, the elements given in the initializer are 
>   added to the collection referenced by the field or property. The field or property must be of a collection type that 
>   satisfies the requirements specified in §7.6.10.3